# How to transform this dataframe to get this json structure?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with this structure:

```
          RegisteredTime                 Start      Value
1    2016-04-17 15:30:00   2016-04-18 00:00:00    1000.00
2    2016-04-17 15:30:00   2016-04-18 01:00:00    2000.00
3    2016-04-17 15:30:00   2016-04-18 02:00:00    3000.00
4    2016-04-17 15:30:00   2016-04-18 03:00:00    4000.00
5    2016-04-17 15:30:00   2016-04-18 04:00:00    5000.00
```

It is sorted by `RegistredTime` and for every `RegisteredTime` there are exactly 24 entries.

I am able to convert to json with `df.to_json(orient='record')` which gives me something like:

```
[
    {
        "RegisteredTime": "2016-04-17 15:30:00",
        "Start": "2016-04-18T00:00:00",
        "Value": 1000.00,
    },
    {
        "RegisteredTime": "2016-04-17 15:30:00",
        "Start": "2016-04-18T0:00:00",
        "Value": 2000.00,
    },
    ...
]
```

I have minimal experience with pandas and the structure that I would really like to have is this one:

```
[ 

    {
        "SamplingTime": "2016-04-17 15:30:00",
        "Values": [
                      {
                          "Start": "2016-04-18T00:00:00",
                          "Value": 1000.00
                      },
                      {
                          "Start": "2016-04-18T01:00:00",
                          "Value": 2000.00
                      },
                      ...
                  ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Could someone please help me how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by `SamplingTime` and calling `to_dict` twice (one on groups, one on the whole set) should do what you want.

```
df2 = df.rename(columns = {"RegisteredTime": "SamplingTime"}) #assigning to another df in case you want to keep the original column name 
df2.head(10)
Out[196]: 
       SamplingTime             Start  Value
0  17/04/2016 15:30  18/04/2016 00:00   1000
1  17/04/2016 15:30  18/04/2016 01:00   2000
2  17/04/2016 15:30  18/04/2016 02:00   3000
3  17/04/2016 15:30  18/04/2016 03:00   4000
4  17/04/2016 15:30  18/04/2016 04:00   5000
5  17/04/2016 15:40  18/04/2016 00:00   1000
6  17/04/2016 15:40  18/04/2016 01:00   2000
7  17/04/2016 15:40  18/04/2016 02:00   3000
8  17/04/2016 15:40  18/04/2016 03:00   4000
9  17/04/2016 15:40  18/04/2016 04:00   5000
```

---

```
dtj = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby("SamplingTime")["Start", "Value"].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict("r")), columns = ["Values"]).reset_index().to_dict("r")

print(dtj)
Out[199]: 
[{'SamplingTime': '17/04/2016 15:30',
  'Values': [{'Start': '18/04/2016 00:00', 'Value': 1000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 01:00', 'Value': 2000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 02:00', 'Value': 3000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 03:00', 'Value': 4000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 04:00', 'Value': 5000L}]},
 {'SamplingTime': '17/04/2016 15:40',
  'Values': [{'Start': '18/04/2016 00:00', 'Value': 1000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 01:00', 'Value': 2000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 02:00', 'Value': 3000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 03:00', 'Value': 4000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 04:00', 'Value': 5000L}]},
 {'SamplingTime': '17/04/2016 15:50',
  'Values': [{'Start': '18/04/2016 00:00', 'Value': 1000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 01:00', 'Value': 2000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 02:00', 'Value': 3000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 03:00', 'Value': 4000L},
   {'Start': '18/04/2016 04:00', 'Value': 5000L}]}]
```

This is a list so if you need it as a JSON string you can just call `json.dumps(dtj)` or you can change the last `to_dict` to `to.json(orient = "records")`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to group your results by RegisteredTime.

You can start by putting your data into several dicts (like you did when calling the to_json method, after that something like this:

```
data = {}
for data_point in my_data:
    time = data_point['RegisteredTime']
    if time not in data:
        data[time] = []
    d = {}
    d['Start'] = data_point['Start']
    d['Value'] = data_point['Value']
    data[time].append(d)

result = []
for key, value in data.items():
    result.append({
        'SamplingTime': key,
        'Values': value
    })
```

after this the list result contains all the information in the format you wanted.

This is probably not the most "pythonic" way of solving it, but i tried to split the steps so that it was easier to understand. Hope it helped.